# How to sum application of function to each 3d matrix inside an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `np.ndarray` of 4 dimensions (x, y, z, p) and want to add the results of applying a function over each matrix (y, z, p) inside the `x` dimension.

What I want to do is something like:

```
a = np.random.random((4, 12, 10, 100))
collect += np.greater(a, 10)
```

Thus, `collect` should have the sum of `np.greater(a[0], 10) + np.greater(a[1], 10) + np.greater(a[2], 10) + np.greater(a[3], 10)` and shape `(12, 10, 100)`.

Is there a way to do such thing with numpy without an explicit loop traversing all elements inside `x` dimension?

Comment: So you are looking to sum the boolean mask along axis zero? Can't you just do `np.sum(np.greater(a, 10).astype(int), axis=0)`?

Comment: You probably looking for numpy.einsum https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 yes, this does the job! I was so obfuscated with my problem that didn't get to see such simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: @woblob. Now I have to post an answer showing how to use `einsum` even though it's totally not applicable to the situation... :)

Comment: @Tgsmith61591. Why are you doing `astype(int)`? Sum will take care of it for you.

Comment: @woblob. I've posted an answer that uses einsum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution for adding all the numbers along an axis is of course to add the numbers along that axis:

```
a = np.random.randint(20, size=(4, 12, 10, 100))
np.sum(a > 10, axis=0)
```

or more concisely:

```
(a > 10).sum(0)
```

There are other ways of doing the same thing. Absolutely massive overkill is the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046626/how-to-sum-application-of-function-to-each-3d-matrix-inside-an-array/64050042#comment113255748_64046626) to use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) on a single array. In this case, you do have to explicitly convert the input to an integer, since `einsum` does not promote booleans to integers, unlike `sum`:

```
np.einsum('ijkl->jkl', (a > 10).astype(int))
```

The condition `np.greater(a, 10)` is more intuitive as `a > 10`, and will always be false for `np.random.random`, since that generates in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: @Divakar. As long as the first dimension is no larger than 255 elements.

Comment: @Divakar. Because the sum could overflow, no?

Comment: Ah yeah that's true!